# Simplifying an integral rational function

Tags: integration, polynomials

I have an improper fraction that looks like this: $\int \frac{x^2+1}{x^2-5x+6}dx$

I wanted to know what's the best way to simplify this?

For example, an improper fraction is given when $n \ge m$. In the book I'm currently reading, it mentions to work out the integral by always dividing the numerator by the denominator, and obtaining a polynomial plus a proper fraction.

The result should be this: $$\int 1 + \frac{5x-5}{x^2-5x+6}dx$$

However, given the information above I cannot seem to find this answer. Expanding this out it gives the same integral, though what are the steps to achieve an integral in this form?

Comment: $\frac{a_n x^n+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+...+a_0}{b_m x^m+b_{m-1} x^{m-1} + ... +b_0} = \frac{a_n}{b_m} x^{n-m} + \frac{{\rm polynomial\ {\it P}\ of\ degree\ } \leq{n-1}}{b_m x^m+b_{m-1} x^{m-1} + ... +b_0}$. So you can reduce the degree of numerator until it is less than $m$. To find $P$, you can multiply both parts to denominator.

Comment: Are you familiar with [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division)?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thanks for the response, I understand this better now and have got the solution required!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this particular problem is as follows:

$$\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-5x+6} = \frac{x^2-5x+5x-5+5+1}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{(x^2-5x+6)+(5x-5)}{x^2-5x+6} = 1 + \frac{5x-5}{x^2-5x+6}$$